# Which file to edit when adding custom rest api support in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've never worked with php or wordpress but is trying to use an custom post api from wordpress.

I've found this link: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/

where they say that I can just add similar code like below and it should work.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_book_cpt' );
function my_book_cpt() {
$args = array(
  'public'       => true,
  'show_in_rest' => true,
  'label'        => 'Books'
);
register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

But since I'm full newby here I don't know which file to put this in? Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you are working on exactly, this function could be added in your child-theme functions.php file or in a plugin php file.

Comment: @gael thanks for your answer, how do you mean it depends, what does it depend on? I have a custom post on a wordpress site that I would like to read and post to, I got one path wp-content/themes/projectname/functions.php and another wp-includes/functions.php for example

Comment: Definitely in your themes/projectname/functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Johan,  you will need to register a custom WP REST API path in your functions.php, something like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'yourPathName');

function yourPathName(){
    register_rest_route('nameItHere/version#', 'routNameHere', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'nameACallbackFunction',
    ));
}

function nameACallbackFunction($data) {
    $variablename = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'name_of_your_post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        's' => $data['term'],
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc'
    ));

    $anotherVariable = array();

    while ($variableName->have_posts()) {
        $variableName->the_post();
        array_push($anotherVariable, array(
            'id' => get_the_ID(),
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'content' => get_the_content()
        ));
    }

    return $anotherVariable;
}
```

Then you can reference your new endpoint and the data within it in your JS AJAX call using `XMLHttpRequest()`